# Integer Overflows in C and Defenses Against Numeric Errors

Tags: c, integer, overflow

I am trying to research various integer overflow scenarios in C and I was wondering does the C language provide any defenses against numeric errors and are there any additional classes or libraries in the C language that can help with that?  Also, can anyone give me an example of code that results in an integer overflow in C?

Comment: There is no defenses, the overflow occurs that's all (out of _double_). Note there is not only (_unsigned_) _int_ in C but also (_unsigned_) _long long_ for instance. What are the min/max values and operations you need ?

Comment: By the way, *why* do you "research various integer overflow scenarios in C"? Curiosity? Or is there some underlying problem that you need to solve? If you have another problem, then please ask about that directly instead.

Comment: *"Also, can anyone give me an example of code that results in an integer overflow in C?"* You're "trying to research various integer overflow scenarios in C", but you can't come up with your own example of integer overflow in C?

Comment: "an example of code that results in an integer overflow in C?" --> `INT_MAX + 1`

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no defenses.

This overflows:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int a = INT_MAX - 2;
const int b = INT_MAX - 2;
printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a + b);
```

When I tested it it printed -6, but anything could happen I guess.

Comment: When the values are known at compile time, the compiler might warn you about the overflow, although most compilers will still return `-6` if they need to return something anyway. However, if the compiler believes that both `a` and `b` are positive, then `a + b` will be considered as [being positive too in all cases](https://godbolt.org/z/AxeXlw).